# After deploying docker container in Azure. If I browse the url its giving me connection timeout

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-container, azure-container-service

I am deploying the image https://hub.docker.com/r/codercom/code-server which is remote VS code.I have deployed this in Azure as steps mentioned in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-docker-with-azure-container-instances/2-run-aci. After deployment is successful if I browse it , its showing connection timeout

Comment: You need to provide more details. It's not enough to figure out what is the error you meet.

Comment: I am deploying the image https://hub.docker.com/r/codercom/code-server which is remote VS code.I have deployed this in Azure as steps mentioned in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-docker-with-azure-container-instances/2-run-aci. After deployment is successful if I browse it , its showing connection timeout. @CharlesXu

Comment: Put the message in the question. It's more fitting.

Comment: @CharlesXu I have put it there also. Did you find anything about this problem?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Comment: thanks @CharlesXu it solved my problem. I need another help if you don't mind, How can I open any angular project(in fact any project)  in the VSCode hosted in that container.

Comment: You can add another question in SO with more messages as possible and then give me the link. I will take a try.

Comment: @CharlesXu I have added it ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987920/remote-vs-code-development-with-code-server ) did you understand my question right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how do you deploy the container in Azure. But on my side, it works well and finally, you can see the login page as below:

[image]

I think the possible reason is that you forget to change the port into 8080 as the image shows. You can the example command:

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -v "$PWD:/home/coder/project" codercom/code-server
```

So the image exposes the port 8080 which you also need to do like it did. Then the CLI command should be:

```
az container create -g your_group -n aci_name --image codercom/code-server --ip-address Public --ports 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Azure VM, I had to disable the firewall to clear the timeout, otherwise  docker network would not work.

```
root@my_hostname:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere on lo             ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY IN     127.0.0.0/8
9418/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6) on lo        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6)              DENY IN     ::1
9418/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on lo
53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on lo
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

root@my_hostname:~# ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

root@my_hostname:~# docker exec -it v12 sh
/opt/app $ nc -vz my_hostname 8445
my_hostname (my_ip:8445) open
```