# Remote VS Code development with code-server

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-container-service, vscode-remote, azure-container-instances

I have deployed the image https://hub.docker.com/r/codercom/code-server which is remote VS code in Azure containers. But now if I want to open any Project(Eg: Angular Project with node and angular cli setup)in that VS Code and develop remotely how can I achieve this.

Comment: If you mean the VS code is in the container instance, but the projects are in other places, for example, your local machine or Github?

Comment: @CharlesXu no. it can be in same container not in my local machine.how to host project in same container and open it in VSCode.or how to take code from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, I think there are two ways to achieve it.

One is that copy your project to the image and then deploy the image to the ACI. Or copy the project after deploying the image to ACI.

Another is that [mount Azure File share to the ACI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files), and then upload the projects to the Azure file share.

Comment: how can i copy project to that image?  can we run code-server image in another docker file which includes copying of project.Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Don't Mind, I am new to docker ,one week back i started with docker. Bare with my non-sense questions. if you know/have any best materials to get started with docker please let me know.

Comment: @San Yes, I mean to use the Dockerfile to create your own image with copying the project. You can take a look at the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). But I recommend the second way in my answer. It does not need you to create your own image. Just mount the Azure File Share to the ACI and upload your project to the file share.

Comment: check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093103/how-can-i-pass-container-level-arguments-in-azure-container-create

Comment: @San I will take a look later.