# How can I pass container level arguments in azure container create

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

When I run docker locally `"docker run -it -p 8080:8080 codercom/code-server --auth none"` I am using --auth none argument, but how can i use this in azure container create commands.

If I run normally like `"az container create   --resource-group learn-deploy-vsCode   --name code-server   --image codercom/code-server  --auth none  --ports 8080   --dns-name-label san-codeserver   --location eastus" it is throwing error "az: error: unrecognized arguments: --auth none"`.

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile of this image?

Comment: this is from docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/codercom/code-server I dint find any Docker file

Comment: this can be useful https://hub.docker.com/layers/codercom/code-server/latest/images/sha256-ff785c1c004bee0574807e540e205d2d4293a96efb3c521d69f07c99461263d4?context=explore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the command `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 codercom/code-server --auth none` locally, it means you add the parameter `--auth none` for the command in the link you provide. But when you run the CLI command with the parameter `--auth none`, the Azure CLI will look it as the parameter of the CLI command [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create), and this parameter does not support in the CLI.

So what you need to do is change the CLI command like this:

```
az container create --resource-group learn-deploy-vsCode \
--name code-server \
--image codercom/code-server \
--command-line "/usr/local/bin/code-server --host 0.0.0.0 . --auth none" \
--ports 8080 \
--dns-name-label san-codeserver   \
--location eastus
```

Comment: how did you get this --command-line "/usr/local/bin/code-server --host 0.0.0.0 . --auth none" \ ? Is this run in bash of code-server? can you explain in detail?

Comment: @San The parameter `--command-line` will overwrite the command in the Dockerfile. So you need to run the command manually.

Comment: why you added "--host 0.0.0.0 ."?

Comment: @San It's not me, it's the command in the Dockerfile. But I can tell you that it means the application listens to the address 0.0.0.0 and it can receive all the requests to this machine.

Comment: where did you get docker file for it?

Comment: can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386014/problem-in-running-code-server-in-https-secure

Comment: @San Yeah, I will take a try.