# Problem in running code-server in https secure

Tags: docker, containers, docker-container

If we run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 sanjayme/vscode-dotnet-core --auth none --cert` still we are facing not secure connection. How to solve this?

Even we tried something similar to

```
docker \
  -v /path/to/certs.crt:/home/coder/cert.crt \
  -v /path/to/cert-key.key:/home/coder/cert.key \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  run codercom/code-server:v2 \
    --cert /home/coder/cert.crt --cert-key /home/coder/cert.key
```

the http url is working, but if we browse https dns mapped url it's throwing an error. Check the attachment for error:

[image]

Comment: How do you do it when you deploy it without docker?

Comment: @CharlesXu I am deploying with docker only. if I understand your question correctly

Comment: I mean how do you do for the certificate when you do not use the docker, it just the same do it in docker.

Comment: @CharlesXu Tq. can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496659/clone-github-repo-to-docker-container-while-container-creation